# How to remove duplicates from space separated list by Oracle regexp_replace?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a list called 'A B A A C D'. My expected result is 'A B C D'. So far from web I have found out

```
regexp_replace(l_user ,'([^,]+)(,[ ]*\1)+', '\1');
```

Expression. But this is for , separated list. What is the modification need to be done in order to make it space separated list. no need to consider the order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand well you don't simply need to replace ',' with a space, but also to remove duplicates in a smarter way.

If I modify that expression to work with space instead of ',', I get

```
select regexp_replace('A B A A C D' ,'([^ ]+)( [ ]*\1)+', '\1') from dual
```

which gives `'A B A C D'`, not what you need.

A way to get your needed result could be the following, a bit more complicated:

```
with string(s) as ( select 'A B A A C D' from dual)    
    select listagg(case when rn = 1 then str end, ' ') within group (order by lev)
    from (
            select str,  row_number() over (partition by str order by 1) rn, lev
            from (
                SELECT trim(regexp_substr(s, '[^ ]+', 1, level)) str,
                       level as lev
                  FROM string
                CONNECT BY instr(s, ' ', 1, level - 1) > 0
                )
         )
```

My main problem here is that I'm not able to build a regexp that checks for non adjacent duplicates, so I need to split the string, check for duplicates and then aggregate again the non duplicated values, keeping the order.

If you don't mind the order of the tokens in the result string, this can be simplified:

```
with string(s) as ( select 'A B A A C D' from dual)
select listagg(str, ' ') within group (order by 1)
from (
        SELECT distinct trim(regexp_substr(s, '[^ ]+', 1, level)) as str
          FROM string
        CONNECT BY instr(s, ' ', 1, level - 1) > 0
     )
```

Comment: Didn't have to wait long.   :-) However, the only improvement is in the outer query - use only the rows with rn=1. That is the only simplification possible in this case.

Comment: @mathguy - I had the sensation I had too much nesting... :) Still thinking if some regexp combination could avoid splitting, but not too much hope...

Comment: With a long select nesting will be a hit though . still i can sacrifice the processing time over correct solution . Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to keep the component strings in the order of their first occurrence (and not, say, reorder them alphabetically - your example is poorly chosen in this regard, because both lead to the same result), the problem is more complicated, because you must keep track of order too. Then for each letter you must keep just the first occurrence - here is where `row_number()` helps.

```
with
     inputs ( str ) as ( select 'A B A A C D' from dual)
-- end test data; solution begins below this line
select listagg(token, ' ') within group (order by id) as new_str
from (
       select level as id, regexp_substr(str, '[^ ]+', 1, level) as token,
              row_number() over ( 
                             partition by regexp_substr(str, '[^ ]+', 1, level)
                             order by level ) as rn

       from   inputs
       connect by regexp_substr(str, '[^ ]+', 1, level) is not null
     )
where rn = 1
;
```

Comment: Order is not a problem  . if the 'A B A A C D' is a variable how to pass it to here

Comment: What kind of variable? (Or do you mean a value in a column in a table?) If it is a bind variable, for example `:str`, just write `:str` wherever I have the column name `str`. NOTE  -  if you need to do this on a table, and the input table has more than one row, then the "connect by" query will be a little more complicated.

Comment: Also, if the order of tokens in the resulting string does not have to be related to the initial string, then the solution may avoid the subquery-outer query structure (and the use of `row_number()`).

Answer (score 3):

Xquery?

```
select xmlquery('string-join(distinct-values(ora:tokenize(.," ")), " ")' passing  'A B A A C D' returning content) result  from dual
```

Comment: What is needed on one's system to make this work? I just tried it on my machine and the output shown is `(XMLTYPE)`, not `A B C D`.

Comment: wrapp arround `xmlcast( xmlquery(... ) as varchar2(2000)) `