# Remove duplicates from comma separated list with regexp

Tags: oracle, plsql, regexp-replace

I have

```
contract, clause 1, Subsection 1.1, contract, clause 1, Subsection 1.2,
paragraph (a), contract, clause 1, Subsection 1.2, paragraph (b), contract, 
clause 2
```

and I want to get

```
contract, clause 1, Subsection 1.1, Subsection 1.2, paragraph (a), paragraph 
(b), clause 2
```

I've found that regexp can do this but I can not find which string to use to do it

Please help..

Comment: People are probably going to be reluctant to help unless you try it out and post your attempts here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328621/splitting-string-into-multiple-rows-in-oracle) to split a comma separated value into rows, I splitted the string into rows, kept the position of the first occurence, made a distinct a reaggregated the values

```
with test_string as ( 
select 1 as id,
 'contract, clause 1, Subsection 1.1, contract, clause 1, Subsection 1.2, paragraph (a), contract, clause 1, Subsection 1.2, paragraph (b), contract, clause 2' val 
from dual)
select id, listagg(word,', ') WITHIN GROUP (order by position) FROM (
select distinct id, first_value(position) over ( partition by word order by position ) position, word from (
select 
  distinct t.id,
  levels.column_value as position,
  trim(regexp_substr(t.val, '[^,]+', 1, levels.column_value))  as word
from 
  test_string t,
  table(cast(multiset(select level from dual connect by  level <= length (regexp_replace(t.val, '[^,]+'))  + 1) as sys.OdciNumberList)) levels
  )
) GROUP BY id
```

And if you are not interested in keeping the order

```
with test_string as ( 
select 1 as id,
 'contract, clause 1, Subsection 1.1, contract, clause 1, Subsection 1.2, paragraph (a), contract, clause 1, Subsection 1.2, paragraph (b), contract, clause 2' val 
from dual)
select id, listagg(word,', ') WITHIN GROUP (order by 1) FROM (
select 
  distinct t.id,
  trim(regexp_substr(t.val, '[^,]+', 1, levels.column_value))  as word
from 
  test_string t,
  table(cast(multiset(select level from dual connect by  level <= length (regexp_replace(t.val, '[^,]+'))  + 1) as sys.OdciNumberList)) levels
) GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Maybe there is an easier solution but it didn't come to my mind

Comment: Didn't saw that the answer here is quite the same ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259200/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-space-separated-list-by-oracle-regexp-replace ) probably better

Comment: Thanks a lot @LauDec, you solve my problem...